# what is $.expr[":"] in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the link to original code: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/#comment-518214

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/#comment-518214

1) in th above code, what is $.expr[:]? 
2) what is $.expr.createPseudo?

I can't find any document about it!!! Why they provide this without document?  very frustrated!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: it is an internal function o jquery used to create jQuery expressions

Answer (score 7):

> 1) in th above code, what is $.expr[:]? 2) what is $.expr.createPseudo?

It's how you extend Sizzle selectors. See the [docs](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#sizzleselectorscreatepseudofunction).

Sizzle is the DOM query engine used by jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

`$.expr` contains an object that holds reference to the sizzle pseudo selectors. 
`$.expr.createPseudo` is a method designed for extending the `$.expr` object so you can implement new pseudo selectors.

For example,

```
$.expr[':'].wide = $.expr.createPseudo(function () {
    return function (elem) {
        return $(elem).width() > $(elem).height();
    }
});
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaPeC/)

[Here's the github for sizzle docs](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation)